# showing an error as has need to conform the protocol

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, protocols

This is my code:-

Model:-

```
class QuestionListModel: NSObject {

    var optionsModelArray:[OptionsModel] = []

     var question:String!

    init(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {

        guard   let question = dictionary["question"] as? String

             else {
                return

        }

        if let options = dictionary["options"] as? [String]{
            print(options)

            print(options)

            for values in options{

                print(values)

                let optionmodel = NH_OptionsModel(values: values)
                self.optionsModelArray.append(optionmodel)

                         }

        }
              self.question = question
         //   print(self.dataListArray33)
                   }
}
```

optionModel:-

```
class OptionsModel: NSObject {
 var values:String?
         init(values:String) {

           self.values = values
           print( self.values)

        }
 }
```

in viewmodel:-

```
var questionsModelArray:Array<NH_QuestionListModel>? = []
     init(withdatasource  newDatasourceModel:NH_QuestionDataSourceModel) {
            datasourceModel = newDatasourceModel

            print(datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)

             self.questionsModelArray = datasourceModel.dataListArray

            print(self.questionsModelArray)

            print(datasourceModel.dataListArray)
        }


               func numberOfSections() -> Int{

               return (self.questionsModelArray?.count)!

                }

                func titleForHeaderInSection(atindexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> QuestionListModel {

                    return self.questionsModelArray![indexPath.row]

                }

            func numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath:IndexPath) -> Int {

                if  let questionModel = self.questionsModelArray?[indexPath.section]{

                    return questionModel.optionsModelArray.count

               }

              else{
                  return 0

           }                   
           }


            func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> OptionsModel{

               let questionModel = self.questionsModelArray?[indexPath.section]

                           return questionModel!.optionsModelArray[indexPath.row]

            }
```

And in ViewController:-

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return questionViewModel.numberOfSections()

    }


   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: IndexPath) -> UIView? {


        //  let headercell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HeaderCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! NH_questionheader


        let identifier = "HeaderCell"

        var headercell: NH_questionheader! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? NH_questionheader

        if headercell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "NH_questionheader", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            headercell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? NH_questionheader
        }

        headercell.setReviewData(reviews:questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atindexPath:section))

        return headercell
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 150

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: IndexPath) -> Int {

       return questionViewModel.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath: section)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "Cell"
        var cell: CellTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? CellTableViewCell

        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CellTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? CellTableViewCell
        }
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

       cell.setOptions(Options1: questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))

        print("Section \(indexPath.section), Row : \(indexPath.row)")            

        return cell

    }
```

my json file:-

```
{
    "data":[
              {
              "question": "Gender",
              "options": ["Male","Female"]

              },
              {
              "question": "How old are you",
              "options": ["Under 18","Age 18 to 24","Age 25 to 40","Age 41 to 60","Above 60"]
            }, {
            "question": "I am filling the Questionnaire for?",
            "options": ["Myself","Mychild","Partner","Others"]
            }
              ]      
}
```

This is my data .So i need to display the questions in header and options in the cell for index .But showing as error as UITableview has need to conform the protocol UITableviewDataSource.

Also showing error as Index out of range.
How to do.....

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not assign a datasource to your view controller. So please assign it in your `ViewDidLoad` of your view controller

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.yourtableview.delegate = self
    self.yourtableview.dataSource = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when you fail to implement the required methods of a protocol. In this case the methods would be :

1. cellForRowAt
2. numberOfRowsInSection

Since you already have them implemented in your view controller chances are that you might have failed to set the datasource for the table view.

Refer to this
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource

Answer (score 0):

You haven't correctly declared the `numberOfRowsInSection` function; `section` is an `Int`, not an `IndexPath`.  As a result you have not implemented the mandatory functions of `UITableViewDataSource`.

You want:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return questionViewModel.numberOfRowsIn(section: section)
}
```

With an appropriate change in your view model:

```
 func numberOfRowsIn(section:Int) -> Int {
    return self.questionsModelArray?[section].optionsModelArray.count ?? 0

 }
```

I would also suggest that you review your use of implicitly unwrapped optionals and force unwrapping; this is just asking for crashes.

For example, there is no reason for the `question` property of `QuestionListModel` to be `String!`; just declare it as `String` and make your initialiser failable.  Better yet, use `Codable` to create your model from JSON and get rid of all of that code.

You can eliminate the force unwrapping in `numberOfSections` too:

```
func numberOfSections() -> Int {
    return self.questionsModelArray?.count ?? 0
}
```

I would also suggest you make `QuestionListModel` a struct rather than an `NSObject` subclass.

If I were you I would re-factor to remove the view model, it is adding unnecessary complexity in this case, and use `Codable` for your JSON deserialisation:

```
struct Questions: Codable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case questions = "data"
    }

    var questions: [Question]
}

struct Question: Codable {
    var question: String
    var options: [String]
}
```

Your view controller then becomes much simpler:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDatasource {

    var questionData: Questions?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "NH_questionheader", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell")
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CellTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        // You don't show how you load your JSON, but assuming you have it in an instance of `Data` called `jsonData`:
        do {
            self.questionData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Questions.self, from: jsonData)
        } catch { 
            print("Error decoding JSON: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: IndexPath) -> UIView? {

        let identifier = "HeaderCell"

        guard let questionData = self.questionData,
          let headercell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? NH_questionheader  else {
            return nil
        }

        headercell.label.text = questionData.questions[section].question
        return headercell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 150
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.questionData?.questions[section].options.count ?? 0
    } 

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return self.questionData?.questions.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "Cell"
    // Note, I have used force unwrapping and a forced downcast here as if either of these lines fail you have a serious problem and crashing is the simplest way of finding it during development
        let option =  self.questionData!.questions[indexPath.section].options[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath ) as! CellTableViewCell
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
        cell.label.text = option
    return cell

    }

}
```

Once you have this basic approach working you can try and add a view model if you like.

Comment: here showing error as :-use of unresolved identifier indexPath.how to solve

Comment: numberOfRowsIn(section:)  here i need the count of the optionsmodel not questionmodel.How to do

Comment: Why did you use the `OptionsModel` class anyway?  The options are just an array of `String`

Comment: here i cann't able to get the count of optionmodel in  func numberOfRowsInSection(section:Int) -> Int {    how to solve it

Comment: on this line :-  func numberOfRowsInSection(section:Int) -> Int {
        
        self.questionsModelArray = datasourceModel.dataListArray
        
      print(self.questionsModelArray?[section].optionsModelArray.count)
        
        return self.questionsModelArray?[section].optionsModelArray.count ?? 0
        
 
    }

Comment: Please don't be offended if this isn't the case, but it seems that you are new to iOS programming, if not programming in general.  By attempting to adopt MVVM you are making life much harder for yourself.  In my opinion MVVM offers little value in iOS programming unless you are using a binding framework and certainly not in a simple application such as this.

Comment: i need according to model,viewmodel,viewcontroller.i doesn't  need in Struct . according to my json data how to display the data in tableview?

Comment: In general you should always use a struct unless you need a class; structs give you immutability which is typically a good design choice.  If you want to use a view model then you can refactor the code that I have added above; however it just adds complexity.

Answer (score 0):

your view controller cannot find the data source and delegate for the table view. make sure you have assigned the data source and delegate

```
self.yourtableview.delegate = self
self.yourtableview.dataSource = self
```

and also make sure that your controller also inherit the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you should set your VC as the *delegate* and *datasource* of your table.

Option 1, do it dynamically:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Option 2, from your storyboard (example below):

[image]

After this, you should use the following datasource functions of UITableView:

```
// return number of questions
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int

// return number of options per question (indicated by section)
func tableView(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int
```